# LTSpice model of a NE555 as linear ramp generator has wrong frequency

Tags: 555, sawtooth-waveform

So I found the variant of using an NE555 to generate a sawtooth signal by charging the capacitor using a constant current source. The simulation is shown below.

The lower treshold is 1/3 * VDD and the higher treshold ist 2/3 * VDD according to the datasheet. R5 was chosen with 10k.

The way I calculate C is as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}
V_B &= V_{DD} \cdot \frac {R_4} {R_3 + R_4} \\
I_E &= \frac {V_{DD}-V_B-V_{BE}} {R_5} \\
C &= \frac{I_E}{f} \frac {1} {V_{max}-V_{min}}
\end{aligned}$$

\$V_B\$ is the base voltage, base current is neglected, \$V_{max} = 2/3 \cdot V_{DD} = 6{\rm\,V}\$, \$V_{min} = 1/3 \cdot V_{DD} = 3{\rm\,V}\$.
I assumed base-emitter voltage with 0.65V

Now, with a target frequency of 1kHz, the calculated C=128nF, I reach 868Hz instead of 1kHz, that is quite some deviation. The only thing that looks suspicious in the simulation is that the 6V threshold (upper treshold) is exactly 6V, but the lower treshold seems to be lower than the expected 3V. Now for this example it shows as 2.8V which is ok according to the datasheet.

However, If I increase the frequeny to 10kHz, which is for sure not a very high frequency, things got more strange. The calculated C would be 12.8nF in this case. Doing another simulation with that capacitance shows a resulting frequency of 6.34kHz which is extremely far off the targeted 10kHz. Also I see that the ramp discharges down to about 1.49V, while the discharge process should stop at the lower 3V threshold.

I suspected that the slew rate of the discharge ramp is too high so that the internal discharge circuitry is too slow to stop discharging right on time, therefore discharing too much. This again would then lead to a slower frequency.

Since this circuit is found quite often, something must be wrong in my calculation or circuitry.

[image]

The waveform of the ramp for the 10kHz case and the current through R5 are shown below.

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that 100kHz is the top end for the original bipolar 555 so 10kHz is not 'low'. You'll probably get more predictable results with a CMOS version if you really must use a 555.

Comment: I've fixed the title of the question, since you're not asking about an actual 555, and that makes all the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspected that the slew rate of the discharge ramp is too high so that the internal discharge circuitry is too slow to stop discharging right on time, therefore discharging too much. This again would then lead to a slower frequency

You are correct. There are at least three circuits within the 555 that cause the discharge period to extend beyond the ideal. They are:

1. The comparator at 1/3 Vcc.
2. The driver of the discharge transistor.
3. The discharge transistor.

If the lower voltage of the ramp (Vramp_Lo) starts at less than ideal (1/3 Vcc) then the time taken for the ramp to reach the upper threshold (2/3 Vcc) is extended. Assuming the upper point of the ramp is exactly 2/3 Vcc, the the degree of extension can be calculated:

New ramp-up time =  Ideal ramp-up time × (1 + (1/3 Vcc - Vramp_Lo) / (1/3 Vcc) ).

Of course, total period is the sum of ramp-up time & ramp-down time. However, since ramp-down time is very much shorter than ramp-up time, it can be ignored for a first order analysis.

I suggest inserting a resistor in front of the discharge pin to reduce the ramp-down rate. Try values of R that limit the ramp-down rate to about 20 times the ramp-up rate.

Comment: So, calculating the components for this kind of circuit more or less rely on trial/error or simulation? (the vramp_lo can only be found by simulation?)

Comment: The data needed to calculate the frequency accurately are the time delays I mentioned.  Most 555 datasheets do not provide this data.  In that case, yes, trial & error, & simulation, are the only options remaining.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try it with an actual 555, rather than a simulated one. You don't know how good the LTspice model is. It's not their (Linear or Analog's) product, and the model may be quite rudimentary. Its fidelity is not and won't ever be a marketable feature from their POV. You might have more luck with a general purpose circuit simulator that doesn't have its history tied to a chip maker. I'd expect the results to be better in MicroCap, but I have not actually tried, so feel free to correct me here.

This is such a simple circuit you could breadboard it before ever touching the keyboard and mouse :)

> I see that the ramp discharges down to about 1.49V

Be careful. **The simulation of the ramp discharge** behaves that way, yes. Do you want the simulation to work right, or the actual circuit? An actual 555 won't behave this way.

This is thus an important first lesson in circuit simulation. There are tricky corner cases sometimes, and unless you understand how the simulator works, you can run into them inadvertently. Any time you expect things to switch when some voltage crosses a threshold, you have to be extra careful that the simulator has enough information in the model to capture this. Otherwise, the simulator's time resolution is dictated by slew rates of the signals and the time derivatives of the changes in various parameters of internal models.

A higher fidelity transistor-based model of a bipolar 555 would easily capture this nonlinear behavior around the threshold point. I bet you the model in LTspice doesn't, so the simulator has no clue that a transition is about to happen. Some simulators have special comparator behavioral elements that capture transitions at the correct time, independently of the current time step used in simulation. But the model must use such an element, and use it properly. If it doesn't, you'll get this problem.

A hint that the above is happening: forcibly decrease the time step to, say, 10ns. If the frequency changes when you force the time step to be smaller and smaller, you know it's a simulation problem related to state change rates. It's not necessarily a problem with the simulator core, mind you. All reasonable cores have a way of dealing with it. But the model of the 555 must be configured to make the core aware, otherwise it's not an oracle and can't predict that something interesting may be happening at a random point in time - not without possibly rather expensive backtracking. Time backtracking in a 555 simulation is cheap, but in complex circuits it slow things to a crawl. SPICE kernels work best when the time moves in one direction only.

Comment: I can reduce the max.timstep done by LTspice to e.g. 10ns which is for sure small enough and the result is exactly the same. So this is not a problem of the adaptive time stepping of SPICE. Also, I did some measurements in the lab (although have not documented them yet), and it seems that the results aign nicely with the simulation (so the NE555 is just that "bad" (slow) as we expected)